# unable to get/set the value in ngModel

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I'm trying to fetch a value from a password field and use it in my code,
this is the html section im using

```
<input type="password" maxlength="50" placeholder="Password"
          required [(ngModel)]="resetModel.password" name="password" required #password="ngModel">


<input type="password"  maxlength="50" placeholder="Confirm Password"
          required [(ngModel)]="resetModel.confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" required #confirmPassword="ngModel">
```

nowI've initialized this resetModel object in my component.ts file

```
constructor(
public resetModel: Reset) { }
```

and I've a Reset class with these parameters,

```
export class Reset {
public password: string;
public confirmPassword: string;

constructor() {
this.password = '';
    this.confirmPassword = '';
}
}
```

but when I'm trying to load the webpage the following error is being shown

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
>   There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngModel" ("holder="Password"
>                 required [(ngModel)]="resetModel.password" name="password" required [ERROR ->]#password="ngModel">
>                   
>                 
>   "): ng:///ResetPasswordModule/ResetPasswordComponent.html@30:82
>   Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ( maxlength="50" placeholder="Password"
>                 required [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="resetModel.password" name="password" required #password="ngModel">

Comment: Did you import FormsModule?

Comment: Got it thanks a lot guys, I've imported FormsModule and it worked.